# Realtime change the value of a variable android

Tags: java, android

How could I change the value of the variable real time?
For example,

```
Long finalCurrentTime;
final Date currenttime = new Date();
Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                finalCurrentTime = currenttime.getTime();
                                Log.e("Log", finalCurrentTime);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        };

        t.start();
```

After I Log.e() it, it does not change the variable's value realtime. I'd be great if someone answers. Thanks!

Edited

Comment: where you have written Log line in your code?

Comment: where is `Log.e`?

Comment: edited: look now

Comment: What do you want to achive?Can you clarify a little more

Comment: I want to change the value of a variable realtime. Just like in time, for example,
Long Timenow = 312424, after a second, Timenow = 312426 . And past it to another variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would it?  new Date() creates a date for the time WHEN YOU CALL IT.  It does not create a magical self updating variable.  If you want the time again later, you call new Date() again and it will have the time when you made the second call.